# Count values not in another table using Powerpivot

Tags: sql, excel, powerpivot, dax

I have two tables in Powerpivot, Table A & Table B. They both contain keys, yet no Primary Key. What I am trying to do is work out how many of the keys in Table B, **are not in** Table A.

My thoughts so far have been to use DAX (which I am very new to), or a SQL command like this `SELECT A.key FROM A WHERE key NOT IN(SELECT key FROM B)`.

However, I cannot figure out the correct DAX formula, and despite the SQL query logic being correct, I cannot get this to work in Powerpivot.

I would also be open to a 'countif in Table B column'...

Any help would be great.

Thanks - Chris

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with a bit of help from this [page](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/marco_russo/archive/2010/02/09/how-to-relate-tables-in-dax-without-using-relationships.aspx/%22here%22). If there is a match, the value is 1, if not, then 0.

```
=if(LEN(CALCULATE(values(TableA[Key]),filter('TableA',TableA[Key]='TableB'[Key])))>1,1,0)
```